# why are all outputs the same in this C program?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    extern void fun(int);
    void (*p)(int) = fun;
        fun(2);
    (*fun)(2);
    (*p)(2);
    p(2);
    printf("%x %x %x\n",p,fun,*fun);
}

void fun(int i){
    printf("hi %d\n",i);
}
```

Here all function calls are giving the same output. And even `p, fun, *fun` are giving the same address. How can we interpret this?

```
How can fun and *fun be same?
```

Comment: Wasn't there an ancient time when you had to use *fun to dereference function pointers, but the authors of C decided fun was unambiguous and made it so fun(2) would work?

Answer (score 7):

Because C says:

> (C99, 6.5.3.2p4) "The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator;"

`fun` and `*fun` have the same value as they are equivalent.

Comment: but fun contains the address of functions, right. So *fun means the value at that address. So fun and *fun should be different. If it is not, say I have an array A[10], then A and *A should also be same.

Comment: This is a special rule of  `*` operator for functions. For pointers (and assuming `A` is an array is it first converted to a pointer before `*` is applied), the type and the value of `*p` and `p` are different.

Comment: Why is it a special exception for functions.

Comment: @neel because the rules of the `*` operator as they are specified for an object pointer operand would make no sense for a function operand.